# renewalCount() function in countr package in R

Tags: r, optimization, rcpp, rcpparmadillo

I am trying to use `renewalCount()` function in R to get the fitted model of Weibull Distribution. Here is my piece of code:

```r
wei <- renewalCount(formula = packets ~ 1,
                             data = dfdata,
                             dist = "weibull",  weiMethod = "series_acc",
                             computeHessian = FALSE,
                             control = renewal.control(trace = 0))
```

I am facing the following exception while running this:

```
error: Mat::init(): requested size is too large; suggest to enable ARMA_64BIT_WORD
Error in optimx.check(par, optcfg$ufn, optcfg$ugr, optcfg$uhess, lower,  : 
  Cannot evaluate function at initial parameters
```

I am a newbie in the field of R programming and have tried solutions like importing `optimx` and `RcppArmadillo` library but it did not work. Is there a way to enable ARMA_64BIT_WORD in RStudio. Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you considered contacting the maintainer of whichever package contains this function `renewalCount()` ?  Would that be package [Countr](https://cran.r-project.org/package=Countr) ?

Comment: Yes @DirkEddelbuettel the function of `renewalCount()` is provided in CountR package.